# Add checkout step in magento and save the value in database table

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, checkout, php

I followed the steps of [this](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step?facebook=1) link.

and able to add a step into checkout. I have done some modifications in it and added one step (Character field contact_name) in the checkout after payment.

For that I have created an attribute for sale/order contact_name. How do I save the value into the sales order in magento, So that I can fetch the value of that attribute. Also I want to add some conditions for this attribute like it should be lower case only and does not contain spaces.

The main concern in I want to save the contact name in the database and get the value from the database for it.

Comment: Please check this link 

Hope it help to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188758/how-can-i-add-a-driver-tip-in-magento-onepage-checkout-process/16300136#16300136